# Is there a way to override z-index

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension, z-index

I am working on making a Google Chrome extension. Part of this extension injects some HTML into whatever webpage it is loaded with. That HTML is displayed supposed to be displayed on top of the rest of the HTML.  The problem I am having is when I load some pages I can not see the injected HTML while on other pages it does show up. I did some research and tried setting the `z-index` to the maximum value of `2147483647` based on [this post](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/css-z-index#:%7E:text=The%20values%20for%20z%2Dindex,of%20999%2C%209999%20or%2099999.). Even when I did that, on some of the webpages it still did not show up. I am wondering if there is a way I can get the HTML to show up. I looked at the styles on the pages and I might have missed something but I did not see any `z-index` styles.
The following code is:

```css
#reading-lines-injected {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2147483647;
    width: 100%;
}
#top-bar-reading-line, #bottom-bar-reading-line {
    position: relative;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 70%;
}
#gap-reading-line {
    position: relative;
    height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="reading-lines-injected">
   <div id="top-bar-reading-line"></div>
   <div id="gap-reading-line"></div>
   <div id="bottom-bar-reading-line"></div>
</div>
```

Some of the webpages that don't display the HTML: [digitalocean.com](https://www.digitalocean.com/), [schoology.com](https://www.schoology.com/), [hashbangcode.com](https://www.hashbangcode.com/). It does work on [stackoverflow.com[5](https://www.stackoverflow.com/).

Thank you for all of your answers.

Comment: *Where* in the page did you inject that? z-index is context-based.

Comment: I injected it with `document.body.appendChild(main_div);` so it is getting injected to the `<body>` element.

Comment: `2147483647` - why? why do this?

Comment: have you confirmed that the html **and** css exist in those pages where you can't see it

Comment: I used that to see if `z-index` was a problem.

Comment: Yes, I checked and they are there and if I delete the main content I can see them.

Comment: `#reading-lines-injected` doesn't have any position. It might get pushed off the screen. Try adding `top: 0;`

Comment: No it is not getting pushed off of the screen and yes all fo the styles are getting applied.

Comment: When I injected the code into digitalocean.com which you said doesn't work, it was being pushed off the bottom of the screen. Adding `top: 0` to `#reading-lines-injected` put it on the screen again. May you also try this?

Comment: I just realized that I forgot to reload the extension when I added top:0 and now it works. I will also lower the z-index to a more reasonable amount. Thank you for your help :).

Comment: I find that I almost never need to exceed 5 z-index levels. (It's all about stacking contexts)

Comment: Ok. I will try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for future reference, [evolutionxbox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/989920/evolutionxbox) said that when there is no position applied the element might get pushed off of the screen. To prevent that I just added `top:0` to the `#reading-lines-injected` div.

```css
#reading-lines-injected {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2147483647;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
#top-bar-reading-line, #bottom-bar-reading-line {
    position: relative;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 70%;
}
#gap-reading-line {
    position: relative;
    height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="reading-lines-injected">
   <div id="top-bar-reading-line"></div>
   <div id="gap-reading-line"></div>
   <div id="bottom-bar-reading-line"></div>
</div>
```